# Problem with library dlib, error adding symbols: file format not recognized, libdlib.a

Tags: c++, qt, dlib

I am writing c++ program in which I want to use dlib.h. I using Qtcreator, WSL, Linux x64. I checked it and my compilator and system both are in x64. Despite compilation I see error

```
 /usr/local/lib/libdlib.a:-1: error: error adding symbols: file format not recognized
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Also when I try to write `file libdlib.a` in terminal(ubuntu.sdk) i see `libdlib.a: current ar archive`.
How can i fix this error?

I found information about different architecture between file libdlib.a and my architecture but I checked it and don't think is a problem. Please help